# How to use a single frame of a bake for an animation?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, smoke-simulation, fire

I've currently got a model of a pod-racer, which has an engine exhaust plume. This was created using quick smoke and a custom material (not mine) in another file, and then I copied across the result and pasted it 4 times for the different engines (smoke sims don't like the mirror modifier it seems).

I am creating a basic turn-table animation where the camera spins round the whole model, but for a number of reasons I want just a single frame (roughly halfway through) from the smoke/fire sim to be used for the whole animation.

Is there a way to tell Blender to take a single frame from a baked simulation and use that from the beginning to the end of the animation? (In a perfect world, this would also allow me to delete the rest of the cache and keep only the frame I need.)

Comment: Bake the simulation (to a folder). It will create a separate file for each frame. Then (manually) remove all other files and fill them with copies of the file from the desired frame. Change the names accordingly. Also, see [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/69993/30849) answer.