# key frames with physics simulations

Tags: keyframes, smoke-simulation, cloth-simulation, cache

im creating a scene where i have a cloth simulation and a smoke simulation at at the same time

it is for a still image (with scope to animate it in the future).
my problem is this, with both simulations  start from a neutral position in the when the time line is at at frame #0

in the cloth simulation its a neck tie but But completely flat before the wind dynamics start to toss it around

and in the fire (smoke) simulation the flames are yet to be spawned from the emission object

if I liked a particular frame because of way the tie was flapping in the wind
and in a seperate instance how the fire looked (for example further along the timeline when the flames have finnished bursting up and out and have 'settled')

is there a way if isolating the 'pose' both the tie (cloth sim) and fire (smoke sim) like with a key frame to alow the two posess to exist in the same image at the same time

this might also be helpfull when I come to animate the scene for the tie(cloth sim) to already be blowing in the wind and fire(smoke sim) to already be roaring and potentialy be on a short loop (not too worried about seamlessness) of a few frames just enough to give both things a bit of life while not requiring lots frames of processing heavy simulation (especialy the smoke sim i've noticed)

cheers,

Billy

Comment: When you cache out a simulation, the frames are saved to individual files. By simply renaming the files to the corresponding frame numbers you can move them around after having them simulated. See [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/70005/30849) for more details. If you want a still (for now) you will only have to locate two files (smoke and cloth) and you could rename their framesuffix to 0001 to have them both appear at frame 1.

Comment: cheers, I ended up using this method with 3 frames of cache data, is there an easy way of running them as a loop if i were to animate other things in the scene and have those frame flickering away for the duration?

Comment: That's great to hear. I would just duplicate the frame cache files and rename them with any of the methods in the linked answer. I'd have multiple duplicate files.

Comment: cheers, it would be nice if it were possible to run little bits of animation like the 'symbol' feature in Adobe Animate (formaly flash) and I think other adobe video softwares have that im not familliar with yet where frames can run on there own timeline within the main timeline, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

For still images, this is fairly easy, cloth simulation is a modifier, and like any modifier it can be applied. This will apply the simulated shape at the current frame to the mesh, thus allowing you to then change the frame to the one with your preferred smoke simulation state.

If you want to make it look like the cloth is being blown by the smoke, you might want to look into a [wind](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/force_fields/types/wind.html) force field.